# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in line 114

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to add some data to my database, but I'm getting the error Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in /var/www/mandje.php on line 114.
This is the code I'm using:

```
 foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $id => $value){

        $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Producten WHERE ProductID ="'.$id.'" ');
        $query->execute();

        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $price = $row['Prijs'];
            $ProductID = $row['ProductID'];
            }
        $sql="INSERT INTO Bestellingsdetail( Bestelnummer, ProductID, Aantal, Prijs)
        VALUES ($max,$ProductID,$value,$price)";      //<---- line 114
        $count = $db->execute($sql);
```

I don't really get what's going wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What do see if you do `var_dump($max,$ProductID,$value,$price);`?

Comment: I get: object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(49) "SELECT MAX( Bestelnummer ) FROM Bestellingsdetail" } string(2) "17" int(2) string(5) "29.98"

Comment: There's the issue.  What's `$max`?  Where do you set it?

Comment: A couple of lines up I do:
if(isset($_POST["koop"])) 
{  $query = $db->query('SELECT MAX( Bestelnummer ) FROM Bestellingsdetail');
  $query->execute();
  $max = $query;
  $max ++;

Comment: `$max = $query`.  Why are you setting `$max` to `$query`?  I assume you wanted to set it to the query's *result*.

Comment: Yes that is what I want, but how? Sorry kind of in the dark here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the comments, you show the following:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT MAX( Bestelnummer ) FROM Bestellingsdetail');
$query->execute();
$max = $query;
$max++;
```

This is not how you get the *result* from a query.  You are setting `$max` to a `PDOStatement` object.  You need to `fetch()` the result in order to use it.

```
// I've added "AS maxval" to make it easier to get the row
$query = $db->query('SELECT MAX(Bestelnummer) AS maxval FROM Bestellingsdetail');
$max_row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$max = $max_row['maxval'];
$max++;
```

Docs: http://www.php.net/pdo.query

P.S. `$query->execute();` is only needed for prepared statements.  `query()` will execute the query immediately.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $id => $value)
{

        $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Producten WHERE ProductID ="'.$id.'" ');
        $query->execute();

        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {

            $price = $row['Prijs'];
            $ProductID = $row['ProductID'];

        }

$array = array( $max, $ProductID, $value, $price );

$sql->prepare
    ("
    INSERT INTO Bestellingsdetail (Bestelnummer, ProductID, Aantal, Prijs)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    ")

$sql->execute($array);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $id => $value){

        $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `Producten` WHERE ProductID ="'.$id.'" ');
        $query->execute();

        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $price = $row['Prijs'];
            $ProductID = $row['ProductID'];
            }
        $sql="INSERT INTO `Bestellingsdetail`( `Bestelnummer`, `ProductID`, `Aantal`, `Prij`s)
        VALUES ($max,$ProductID,$value,$price)";
        $smtp = $db->prepare($sql);
        $count = $smtp->execute();
```

However, try and use the prepared statements as you are defeating the reason of using PDO and could be at risk of injection:

```
foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $id => $value){

        $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `Producten` WHERE ProductID ="'.$id.'" ');
        $query->execute();

        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $price = $row['Prijs'];
            $ProductID = $row['ProductID'];
            }
        $sql="INSERT INTO `Bestellingsdetail`( `Bestelnummer`, `ProductID`, `Aantal`, `Prijs`)
        VALUES (:max,:ProductID,:value,:price)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':max', $max);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ProductID', $ProductID);
        $stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
        $stmt->bindParam(':price', $price);
        $count = $smtp->execute();
```

Comment: I tried the second method and got: Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in /var/www/mandje.php on line 115
Line 115 is $stmt->bindParam(':max', $max);

Comment: @DeEerlijkeDame sorry try that, named some of them incorrectly and also used bindParam before we set the object to the variable

Comment: Now I get the first error again: Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in /var/www/mandje.php on line 116

Comment: Sorry last line should be $count = $stmt->execute();

Comment: Still the same error:Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in /var/www/mandje.php on line 116